# is it true that $ \frac{1}{\epsilon}\ln (1- \epsilon x) \approx - \frac{1}{1-\epsilon}x $?

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation, approximation-theory

Target is to approximate $\frac{1}{\epsilon}\ln (1- \epsilon x) $ ($\epsilon, x \in (0,1) $). Here is one using $\ln (1+y) \approx y $: 
$$
\frac{1}{\epsilon}\ln (1- \epsilon x)  \approx -x 
$$
I conjecture this is a better approximation although I am not sure how to prove/disprove it: 
$$
\frac{1}{\epsilon}\ln (1- \epsilon x)  \approx - \frac{1}{1-\epsilon}  x
$$

Any ideas?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Corrected.

Comment: @graydad corrected. $x$ is also in the range of (0,1), So that would never happen.

Comment: No, you did not fix the title. The title needs on $x$ on the right side of the expression.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ah fixed (for real)

Comment: Why is this true? I see if $\epsilon$ is close to $1$, the RHS is arbitrarily large while LHS is not.

Comment: May be, we could consider $x \frac{\log(1-y)}y$ with $y=\epsilon x$